# Envelope curve of a fixed length segment

Tags: contest-math, envelope

$A$ is on the positive half of $x$-axis and $B$ is on $y=x(x>0)$. $AB=1$. Find the envelope curve of $AB$ and/or the area below the envelope line.

**My idea:**

$A(a,0)(1\le a\le\sqrt2), B(x,x)(\dfrac{\sqrt2}2\le x\le1)$, so
$(x-a)^2+x^2=1,x=\dfrac{a+\sqrt{2-a^2}}2, AB:y=f(x,a)=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{2-a^2}}{1-a^2}(x-a)$.

Envelope curve: $y=g(x)=\max(f,a)$, aka maximum of $f(x,a)$ when $x$ is fixed. Then $1/2+\int_1^{\sqrt2}g(x)\mathrm dx$ is the answer.

However, I have difficulty calculating $g(x)$. I tried triangular commutator, but it didn't work.
Who can save me? qwq

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE. It is better to put more effort into your post so that more people get ready and willing to help you. Otherwise, your post may get downvotes, or get closed. Indeed, it is against MSE rules to contribute to posts which are just comprised of a single problem with no effort or attempts. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Fixed it!